# multiple functions from one on-input call - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm wondering if it is possible in Polymer to fire multiple functions when using on-click or on-input etc.

For example:

**HTML *(listing them one by one)***

```
<paper-input label="text please" on-input="funct1;funct2"></paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
funct1 : function() {
     code here to do something
},

funct2 : function() {
     code here to do something
},
```

***or........................***

**HTML *(grouping them)***

```
<paper-input label="text please" on-input="allFuncts"></paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
allFuncts : function() {
    funct1;
    funct2;
},

funct1 : function() {
    code here to do something
},

funct2 : function() {
    code here to do something
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly in plain JS:

```
onclick='func1();func2()';
```

Comment: the onclick/oninput plain JS tags don't work in Polymer, they are replaced by on-click and on-input. So this won't work for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer through a bit of research and by asking a colleague.

It is better to write a function that calls the other functions, just remember to add the `this.` prefix if variables are not globally defined.

**HTML**

```
<paper-input label="text please" on-input="allFuncts"></paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
allFuncts : function() {
    this.funct1(); <------------------ This is where I was going wrong
    this.funct2();                     needing the "this." before the 
                                       function call
},

funct1 : function() {
    code here to do something
},

funct2 : function() {
    code here to do something
},
```

**EDIT**

Through playing with this, I have found that you can pass variables from the top function to the called functions within by declaring them globally in the top function (ie. without `var` preceding the variable name). However, I believe that this would lead to insecurity within the code.

```
allFuncts : function() {
     /* var */ variableName = someVariable;

     this.funct1();
     this.funct2();
}

funct1 : function() {
     // can use **variableName** within this function
}
```